# Laggy UI with frequently updating background

Tags: iphone, ios, multithreading, core-animation, quartz-graphics

My app has a "main" view, a custom thumb stick control, and some buttons. The main view has an additional CALayer defined on it whose contents are constantly updated with streamed images. Some code:

Set up the CADisplay link to repeatedly call my draw method:

```
displayLink_ = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(drawSublayers)];
[displayLink_ setFrameInterval:2];
[displayLink_ addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

The method `drawSublayers` draws the CGImage as

```
  CGImageRelease((__bridge CGImageRef) imageLayer_.contents);
  [imageLayer_ setContents:(id)self.cameraImage_.CGImage];
```

The issue is that the thumb stick and other controls are all very laggy. This is because the drawing of the background image eats enough processor that the mainRunLoop gets dragged down and can't keep up. All the posts I've read suggest that moving any UI updates to separate threads won't work (independent test have confirmed this - the method fires, but no drawing occurs).

Any ideas? The background image isn't a priority, i.e., I don't mind that it takes some time to draw it. I just don't want it interfering with the rest of the UI.

Comment: What happens if you put the `self.cameraImage_.CGImage` on a background thread and store it into a property (atomic, of course!) and just do the `_imageLayer.contents=<your-property>` bit in the main thread? Is the slowdown getting the image from the camera or updating the ui? (I suspect the camera)

Comment: It's the call to setContents that's delaying everything. It forces a redraw of the screen, which eats up enough CPU to slow everything else down.

Comment: So if you replace `[imageLayer_ setContents:(id)self.cameraImage_.CGImage];` with just `self.cameraImage_.CGImage` you don't get the slowdown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your drawing off the main thread. `performSelectorinBackground:`

http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/asynchronous_iphone_nsthread_nstimer

Comment: What about UI actions not being thread safe? Shouldn't the `imageLayer_.contents=...` be done on the main thread?

Comment: That doesn't involve the UI. That just draws the camera image.

Comment: This draws the image still, but now the drawing is far more delayed, and it (for some strange reason) still hasn't stopped the lagginess in other controls. If I stop drawing the image altogether, the other controls are much more responsive, which is why I think it's the culprit.

Comment: Update: this does seem to work, and the lagginess really goes away once I build in release mode.